# Exceção ao rodar projeto

Tags: java-ee, jsf, maven

Tenho um projeto `Maven` onde tentei adicionar uma dependência mais recente do `JSF` depois dessas tentativas o projeto sempre apresentava erros. Criei um projeto novo e copiei todas as classes, páginas etc. Agora toda vez que rodo esse projeto é lançada a seguinte exceção:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
```

O Projeto está funcionando normalmente, mas não sei se esse erro pode influenciar em algo agora ou no futuro então gostaria de resolve-lo.

Dependência que estou usando do JSF:

```
<!-- Implementação do JSF 2.2 -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.8</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Web.xml(Para o projeto funcionar tive que trocar o `version` de 2.5 para 3.0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SistemaSuspensao</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <context-param>
    <description>Quando for atualizar o sistema no datacenter, colocar em Production, e aqui na HR colocar em Development</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>hot-sneaks</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/Login.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

</web-app>
```